# How to index a table using column of another table having relation with it?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index, schema

I have two tables, `Pilot` and `Company`. My queries will be searching for the `Pilots` using the `CompanyName`. For example, I want to get Pilots in a company named 'Boeing'. How should I write my `CREATE INDEX` in SQL Server to optimize my search queries?

Here are my tables:

```sql
-- Company
CREATE TABLE dbo.Company(
    CompanyID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Company PRIMARY KEY,   
    CompanyName NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);

-- Pilot
CREATE TABLE dbo.Pilot (
    PilotID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Pilot PRIMARY KEY,   
    Name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    CompanyID INT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Pilot_Company FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID ) REFERENCES dbo.Company (CompanyID),
);
```

Comment: The main point you have not mention is current SELECT queries you will search with. For example which field is always in WHERE condition which one not.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get Pilots in a company named 'Boeing'. How should I write
> my CREATE INDEX in SQL Server to optimize my search queries?

Given a query like:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, p.Name AS PilotName
FROM dbo.Company AS c
JOIN dbo.Pilot AS p ON p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
WHERE
    c.CompanyName = @CompanyName;
```

An index on CompanyName is needed for the WHERE clause predicate and an index on `dbo.Pilot.CompanyID` to optimize the join on the foreign key.

I suggest a unique constraint on CompanyName as this will ensure data integrity as well as provide the useful unique index.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Company
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Company_CompanyName UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (CompanyName);

CREATE INDEX IDX_Pilot_CompanyID
    ON dbo.Pilot (CompanyID);
```

Answer (score 1):

An [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver16) is effectively a multi-table index. The server will automatically maintain this view in line with the main tables

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW dbo.PilotByCompany
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS

SELECT
  c.CompanyID
  c.CompanyName
  p.PilotID,
  p.Name
FROM dbo.Company c
JOIN dbo.Pilot p ON p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID;
```

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX ON dbo.PilotByCompany (CompanyName, CompanyID, PilotID);
```

Now when you query the view, you will be able to query it efficiently by `CompanyName`. You can also add non-clustered indexes.

If you are using an edition of SQL Server that is not Enterprise or Developer then in order for the optimizer to utilize this index, you must query the view directly (not the base tables) **and use the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint.** I would advise to use this hint anyway, because [it can give efficiencies](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints) even in those version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is going to look something like this:

```sql
SELECT          p.[Name]
FROM            dbo.Company as c
    INNER JOIN  dbo.Pilot AS p
        ON      c.[CompanyID] = p.[CompanyID]
WHERE           c.[CompanyName] = 'Boeing' ;
```

I'd create one index on the Company table to optimise filtering on the CompanyName:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Company_CompanyName]
    ON dbo.Company
    ( [CompanyName] ASC );
```

And one on the Pilot table to optimise joining on the CompanyID, with the Name column tagged on, in case Boeing has a lot of pilots and you want to slap an ORDER BY clause on the query:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Pilot_CompantyID_Name]
    ON dbo.Pilot
    ( [CompanyID] ASC, [Name] ASC ) ;
```

The usual caveats apply about balancing reads and writes, from and to, your nonclustered indexes.